# Finding the parent of an object that is from a certain type

Tags: ios, structure

I have an Object class that has these properties:

- name
- type
- children

`type` holds three possibilities: car, boat, bike.
`children` is an array the holds the children of that object.

So I can have records like this:

```
name = "Project Titan"
type = "car"


name = "Prototype 1"
type = "car"


name = "Tail light"
type = "parts"


name = "Horns"
type = "parts"


name = "Prototype 2"
type = "car"


name = "Wheel"
type = "parts"
```

and organized like this

```
            Project Titan
                   |
          ___________________
         |                   |
         |                   |
    Prototype 1          Prototype 2
         |                   |
    __________              wheel
   |          |
   Tail     horns
   light
```

Or in other words

`Tail Light` and `Horns` are children of `Prototype 1`.
`Wheel` is child of `Prototype 2`
`Prototype 1` and `2` are children of `Project Titan`.

Now suppose I have the object Tail Light and want to know its parent of kind car more immediate, that in this case will be `Prototype 1`. What is the best way to do that without burn the brain?

Ok, you can scan and scan the children of all nodes of the structure, from the top down, until you find the nearest parent up in the structure that is from type = car, but this scanning all structure method appears to be an horrid solution, specially if the structure has hundreds of branches...

Any ideas?

Comment: Add a fourth property - `parent`. This this becomes simple. Just make sure it is a `weak` property.

Comment: DUHH! I need more coffee... I did not see that coming! Please convert your comment to an answer, so I can accept. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to support bi-directional navigation of your nodes is to add a `parent` property to your class. The important thing to remember is to make this a `weak` property to avoid a reference cycle between a parent and its children.

Comment: without abusing your good will and if I had to find an object on that structure by the name? Any magical solugion ?

Comment: You just want to find any object with a given name? You need to do a full traversal of the tree checking each object's name. That's a simple recursive algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

Try this way. In children you will give name of newly created model. And For first class object parent will be nil and if it has new child then pass the reference of parent Model.

```
@interface Model : NSObject

@property(nonatomic,strong) NSString *name;
@property(nonatomic,strong) NSString *type;
@property(nonatomic,weak) Model *children;
@property(nonatomic,weak) Model *parent;

@end
```